# How scrape multiple pages and differents items for each page?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm beginner in python, just some weeks trying to do my webscrape. 
I need to scrape multiple pages of one restaurant on tripadvisor, using beautifulsoup on windows32. In each page, I need to take restaurants name, socialclass and cuisines/dishes, client's name, date's review, titre's review and review.

I tryed  this code in a python console:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

for i in range(260,1231):
    my_url = "https://www.tripadvisor.fr/Restaurant_Review-g187147-d6575305-Reviews-or260-Il_Etait_Un_Square-Paris_Ile_de_France.html".format(i)
    Inf_avis = uReq(my_url)
    page_html = Inf_avis.read()
    Inf_avis.close()
    page_soup = soup (page_html, "html.parser")
    restaurant = page_soup.findAll("div", {"id":"atf_header"})
```

and here Python doesn't paste (It seems blocked?...)the other code to take information about restaurant.

for rest_info in restaurant:

```
try:
    rest_name = restaurant.findAll("h1", {"class":"ui_header h1"})
    inf_rest_name = rest_name[0].text 
    econ_class_food= restaurant.findAll("div, {"class":"header_links"})
    rest_eclf = econ_class_food[0].text
    print(inf_rest_name, rest_eclf)
```

What can I do?? can you help please?? 
I will appreciate all information you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you some cheat sheet that will help you.

- I would propose to use some ready solution like Scrapy
- Try to avoid using synchronous http client like `urllib` or `requests`
- Check if the page that you try to load isn't required Js rendering, for example, it can be SPA or data store in `<script>` tag, or even Js makes AJAX requests, etc
- If the site does not work without Js - go to the developer console -> network -> XHR and reload your page. There you will see all AJAX request.

  In your case, it's not needed, because of tripadvisor store all data in html. Here is the code that will give you the info. `findAll` is an old version,
  `find_all` is a replacement for it. For avoiding this `rest_name[0].text` you can use just `find()` function of your soup object. But I really recommended you to use an easier solution for this, because a lot of work has to be done before you will finish your crawler. If you have any question - feel free

```
r = page_soup.select_one('div#atf_header')
rest_name = r.select_one('div.restaurantName h1').text
econ_class_food = [i.text for i in r.select('div.header_links a')]
```

**UPD 1:** This part is useless `my_url = "https://www.tripadvisor.fr/Restaurant_Review-g187147-d6575305-Reviews-or260-Il_Etait_Un_Square-Paris_Ile_de_France.html".format(i)` in url string you don't have `{}` for formating. You will make a lot of requests to the same page

Comment: No yet. After send my message. Python told me this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\lib\http\client.py", line 470, in read
    s = self._safe_read(self.length)
  File "C:\Python\lib\http\client.py", line 622, in _safe_read
    raise IncompleteRead(b''.join(s), amt)
http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(6633 bytes read, 1 more expected)

Comment: for rest_info in restaurant:
...         try:
...             rest_name = restaurant.findAll("h1", {"class":"ui_header h1"})
...             inf_rest_name = rest_name[0].text
...             econ_class_food= restaurant.findAll("div", {"class":"header_links"})
...             rest_eclf = econ_class_food[0].text
...             print(inf_rest_name, rest_eclf)for rest_info in restaurant:
  File "<stdin>", line 7
    print(inf_rest_name, rest_eclf)for rest_info in restaurant:
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: try:
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    try:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>             rest_name = restaurant.findAll("h1", {"class":"ui_header h1"})
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    rest_name = restaurant.findAll("h1", {"class":"ui_header h1"})
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>             inf_rest_name = rest_name[0].text
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    inf_rest_name = rest_name[0].text

Comment: and much more erros.

Comment: 2 things: 1. add all your code and traceback here. 2. Did you try to run my code because it works for me. ` IncompleteRead(6633 bytes read, 1 more expected)` means that you didn't read all response data

Comment: I answer to your points : 1. I can't add all my code here because there is a characters limit. I tryed it and it doesn't work. 2. when you say that I didn't read all response data, I have to copy again the page ? or What I have to do ?... I'm sorry but I don't have a lot of experience on python.

Comment: I have another question : when you say that I don't have {} in my_url, I have to put: my_url = {"https://www.tripadvisor.fr/Restaurant_Review-g187147-d6575305-Reviews-or260-Il_Etait_Un_Square-Paris_Ile_de_France.html"} ...?

Comment: 1 - you can use gist or pastebin for add all your code
2 - it's about data that you received from the server
3 - I don't have {} in my_url: the code `for i in range(260,1231)` will make almost 1K request to the same page

Comment: My first code:               from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

for i in range(260,1231):
    my_url = "https://www.tripadvisor.fr/Restaurant_Review-g187147-d6575305-Reviews-or260-Il_Etait_Un_Square-Paris_Ile_de_France.html".format(i)
    Inf_avis = uReq(my_url)
    page_html = Inf_avis.read()
    Inf_avis.close()
    page_soup = soup (page_html, "html.parser")
    r = page_soup.select_one("div#atf_header")
    rest_name = r.select_one("div.restaurantName h1").text
    econ_class_food= [i.text for i in r.select("div.header_links a")]

Comment: the second part is this one :          for r in containers:
            try:
                containers = page_soup.find_all("div", {"class":"review-container"})

Comment: and finally : for container in containers:
try: author = containers[0].find_all("div", {"class":"info_text"})
                client_author = author[0].text
                date_review = container.find_all("span", {"class":"ratingDate"})
                date_rev_cl = date_review[0].text.strip()
                titre_review = container.find_all("span", {"class":"noQuotes"})
                titre_rev_cl = titre_review[0].text.strip()
                opinion = container.find_all("p", {"class":"partial_entry"})
                opinion_cl = opinion[0].text.replace("\n","")

Comment: I have another question , is it normal that ...when I run your code at the end I have . . .  instead of >>>?

Comment: It depends on how you run it. But it doesn't matter because it becomes an off topic

Comment: Excuse me, i have another question. I try to open my file with this code :                                                     filename = "revies3.csv"                                                 with open("filename", "w") as f:                                                                 Headers = "rest_name, econ_class_food, author, date\n"                  f.write("headers")                                                                          And I have this error "NameError: name 'f' is not defined". What am i doing wrong?

Comment: open("filename", "w") -> open(filename, "w") because of filename = "revies3.csv"
or open(revies3.csv, "w")

Comment: if I try with open(filename, "w") I have error: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'revies3.csv' .............. if I try with open (revies3.csv, "w") I have error: NameError: name 'revies3' is not defined